# Help with basic Iphone view navigation

Tags: iphone

I am new to iphone development and trying to understand the concept of how to organize navigation between views. What is the simplest way to launch a new view from within your current view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to use a UINavigationController. The docs are available here:[UINavigationController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UINavigationController)

Comment: The examples I have seen implement a UINavigationController by linking it to the app delegate and the main window... if my application's root controller is a tab bar controller, can I make one of the tabs link to a separate UINavigationController that just handles the navigation for that tab?

Comment: OK thanks for your documentation reference. I think I found the information I need to absorb here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CombiningViewControllers/CombiningViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH104-SW1